# Searching through a list using recursion in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to learn recursion but I can't seem to be able to solve a problem. What I'm trying to do is to search for an element through a list but I'm not sure if the way I did it is good.

Here is what I wrote:

```
def srch(item,myList):
    if myList == []:
        return -1
    if myList[0] == item:
        return True
    elif myList[0] != item:
        return srch(item,myList[1:])
```

It seems to be working but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it just by using my 2 parameters?

Comment: Why are you returning `True` if the item is found and `-1` if it isn't?

Comment: @user2357112 I typed something random to see if it was working. But I'm not sure if I made a correct use of the if and elif.

Comment: This looks like a good way to blow the stack. Python 3 doesn't optimize tail calls, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't say it's better, but it is shorter...

```
def srch(item, myList, i=0):
  if i < len(myList):
    return myList[i] == item or srch(item, myList, i+1)
  return -1
```

Comment: The use of `pop` mangles the list given as an input, which is generally undesirable. Also, nonempty lists are considered true values, so you don't need to call `len` on the list.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks for the suggestion. I've made the correction